# How can i set mark for textView?

Tags: ruby, search, gtk, find

i am doing "find and repleace button" for my application. I am using gtk and ruby.  And i can find that how many word, if there is. Also i want to get selection word that searched word, and i should mark them. My some code:

```
def search(ent, txtvu)
start = txtvu.buffer.start_iter
first, last = start.forward_search(ent.text, Gtk::TextIter::SEARCH_TEXT_ONLY, nil)
count = 0
while (first)
mark = start.buffer.create_mark(nil, first, false)
txtvu.scroll_mark_onscreen(mark)
txtvu.buffer.delete_mark(mark)
txtvu.buffer.select_range(first, last)
start.forward_char
first, last = start.forward_search(ent.text, Gtk::TextIter::SEARCH_TEXT_ONLY, nil)
start = first
count += 1
end
```

`count` says me how many words involve My code does't work. :( Why? I want to mark all searched words.

Comment: Would you please provide the example of fail? Count is not counting? Selection is not applied? Is it `Ruby-GNOME2`? If yes, the documentation clearly says, that [select_range](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ATextBuffer#select_range) shouldn’t work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to highlight *all* found words, not just one. In that case, `select_range` is not the function to call, because it will change the selection to the current word, and `GtkTextView` selection is single and contiguous.

Instead, create a highlight tag and apply it to all searches. For example:

```
# create the "highlight" tag (run this only once)
textvu.buffer.create_tag("highlight", {background => "yellow"})

# ... later, in the loop:
textvu.buffer.apply_tag("highlight", first, last)
```

Your matches will all appear highlighted.